# Empty test suite: /InstrumentationResultParser: test run failed: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''

Tags: robolectric, android-testing

Initially, I wrote Android test cases. They worked absolutely fine. But after I tried Robolectric and then switched back to Android test framework, I started getting this error. However, after the error,  I get the message `Empty test suite`.

The stacktrace:

```
12:47:08 I/RemoteAndroidTest: Running am instrument -w -r  -e debug false -e class in.dash.dashapp.ApplicationTest  in.dash.dashapp.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on Nexus_4_API_17_2 [emulator-5554]

12:47:08 I/InstrumentationResultParser: test run failed: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''
```

Comment: If you try clean build is it reproducible?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Got over the issue. There was a problem in my Content Provider. Thanks for trying to help.